# Function returns nothing (not even undefined)

Tags: javascript, function

```
 var hi = function(type) {
    if (type == "boss") {
        return function(name) {
            alert("Hi chief " + name);
        };
    } else {
        return function(name) {
            alert("Hi " + name);
        };
    }
};

hi("boss"); // this will do nothing

var returnedFunction = hi();

returnedFunction("boss"); // prompt "Hi boss"

returnedFunction = hi("boss");

returnedFunction(); // prompt "Hi chief undefined"

returnedFunction("Douglas"); // prompt "Hi chief Douglas";
```

Ok so I understand pretty much everything that's going on except the first one:

```
hi("boss"); // this will do nothing
```

I would expect it to return "Hi chief undefined".

Doesn't the "boss" argument would mean it enters the if statement, where it should execute the function with argument name being undefined: hence you should get "Hi chief undefined".

Any information on how/why I get this behaviour would be most welcome. I am trying to understand and learn the basics of javascript !

Kind regards

Comment: The `hi` function returns a reference to another function. It will not return `Hi chief undefined` because you don't have `return "SOME STRING"` inside your `hi` function.

Comment: `hi("boss")` returns another function. Why would you expect it to return anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns only function, it doesn't execute it. You would have to write:

```
hi("boss")(); // it would print Hi chief undefined
```

in order to execute it

You could probably say that

```
hi("boss");
```

is equaivelnt of writing

```
function(name) {
  alert("Hi chief " + name);
};
```

While writing

```
hi("boss")();
```

is like wiring

```
function(name) {
  alert("Hi chief " + name);
}(); // notiice the ()
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now ! You can return a function without actually executing it.

Comment: @Devilution yes eaxctly! That is an importnat concept in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

`hi("boss");` This line of code will return

```
function (name) {
     alert("Hi chief " + name);
 }
```

this function.

Now you have to execute it.

in order to execute it just write `hi("boss")();`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
var hi = function(type, name) {
    if (type == "boss") {
        alert("Hi chief " + name);
    } else {
        alert("Hi " + name);
    }
};
```

Comment: I know it's possible to make it easier, but it's an excerise for myself to understand what exactly is being run and how the logic behind javascript functions work.

Answer (score -1):

`

```
var hi = function(type) {
    if (type == "boss") {
        return function(name) {
            alert("Hi chief " + name);
        };
    } else {
        return function(name) {
            alert("Hi " + name);
        };
    }
};


//return a function not excecuted
// hi();

// x is the returned function
var x = hi("boss");
x("name");

// 2 
// hi("boss")("name");
```

`

Comment: Consider providing an explanation of the changes you've made and the reason for them

Comment: Then use translators or try your best to explain in English, someone might correct your grammar. That's hardly an excuse for a low-quality answer